# Windows Batch Script: Redirect ALL output to a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, dacapo

I am running various Java benchmarks and would like to archive the results. I execute the (dacapo) benchmark like this:

```
C:\VM\jre\bin\java  -jar C:\benchmarks\dacapo-9.12-bach.jar %arg1% > %time::=%
```

I pass the type of benchmark in over a parameter, thats what %arg1% is.

You can see that I am redirecting the output to a textfile. Unfortunately, the first and last line of the output is still printed in the console and not into the textfile:

```
===== DaCapo 9.12 luindex starting =====
===== DaCapo 9.12 luindex PASSED in 2000 msec =====
```

Especially the last line would be important to have in the text file :)

Is there a trick to force this behavior?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You must redirect *STDOUT* and *STDERR*.

`command > logfile 2>&1`

*STDIN* is file descriptor #0, *STDOUT* is file descriptor #1 and *STDERR* is file descriptor #2.
Just as "command > file" redirects *STDOUT* to a file, you may also redirect arbitrary file descriptors to each other. The `>&` operator redirects between file descriptors. So, `2 >& 1` redirects all *STDERR* output to *STDOUT*.

Furthermore, take care to add `2>&1` at the end of the instruction because on Windows, the order of redirection is important as `command 2>&1 > logfile` will produce an empty file, as Dawid added in the comments.

Comment: What does the 2>&1 even mean?  To say it's unintuitive syntax would be a compliment of the highest order.

Comment: STDIN is file descriptor #0.  STDOUT is file descriptor #1.  STDERR is file descriptor #2.  Just as "command > file" redirects STDOUT to a file, you may also redirect arbitrary file descriptors to eachother.  The ">&" operator redirects between file descriptors.  So, "2 >& 1" redirects all STDERR output to STDOUT.

Comment: Thank you so much, Zach, this demystifies it!

Comment: @ZachRiggle upvoted, but could you please add your comment about STDIN/STDERR and the explanation to the answer? I think this is very helpful info!

Comment: on windows order of redirections is important as `command 2>&1 > logfile` will produce empty file

Answer (score 8):

Add 2>&1 to your command:

```
 C:\VM\jre\bin\java  -jar C:\benchmarks\dacapo-9.12-bach.jar %arg1% 2>&1 > %time::=%
```

This will redirect STDERR to STDOUT which is then redirected into your textfile.