# How to redirect net command output to file in windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to redirect the statements it puts on the console into a file in windows batch code. I am using the net stop command to stop a service.

When I do this:

```
net stop SPTimerV4 2>> mylog.log
```

it appends error text into the file. But it still prints the regular text on the console:

```
The SharePoint 2010 Timer service is stopping.
The SharePoint 2010 Timer service was stopped successfully.
```

How can I even redirect this to a file?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Script: Redirect ALL output to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346863/windows-batch-script-redirect-all-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net stop SPTimerV4 >> mylog.log 2>&1` is what you're looking for.

This works by redirecting all normal output to the log file (the >>) and redirecting error output a copy of the normal output at that moment, which is appending to a file.

Because it redirects to a copy, you can't actually switch them around (eg. `2>&1 1>> mylog.log` won't work)

For more information regarding redirection, please look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)